# запрос в mysql из pythonanywhere ошибка 1146. Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Задача: 
с помощью кода на python авторизоваться в mysql, запускаемый с pythonanywhere.com

```
database = pymysql.connect(user='Lerozo',
                           password='pass',
                           host='Lerozo.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
                           database='Lerozo$social',
                           use_unicode=True,
                           autocommit=True)
```

при выполнении:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT date FROM mail WHERE is_parsed = '0'""")
```

получаю ошибку:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Lerozo$social.mail' doesn't exist")
```

я не понимаю, что я делаю не так

Comment: а у вас есть таблица `mail`? Что возвращает запрос: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'Lerozo$social'`?

Comment: таблица mail есть.
Этот запрос возвращает 0 строк

Comment: Значит либо БД называется по-другому либо в этой БД нет таблиц. Что выдает: `SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables`?

Comment: БД называется social.
2 строки:
information_schema
social

Comment: ну тогда ее и надо указывать: `database='social'`

Comment: Я пробовал, тогда получается другая ошибка:
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'Lerozo'@'%' to database 'social'")

Comment: тогда попробуйте указывать полное имя таблицы: `cursor.execute("""SELECT date FROM social.mail WHERE is_parsed = '0'""")`

Comment: и я бы еще попробовал использовать `lerozo` вместо `Lerozo`

Comment: новая ошибка:
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1142, "SELECT command denied to user 'Lerozo'@'10.0.0.4' for table 'mail'")